# Why disk clone using dd takes more space then actual data size?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I'm trying to clone a disk using `dd` command. 
My input disk size is 1Tb which is only 10% filled. 
My Output disk size is 300Gb which is more than I expected to clone.

But after my cloning got over, I could see this message: 
`No space left on device`.

This is a bit weird how 10% of 1Tb  filled 300Gb space.
Can anyone explain me this thing, why this happened?
Did my data get corrupt?

Comment: Cloning a disk clones the disk. Did you mean to copy the files?

Comment: I can imagine trying to semi-clone a disk with `dd` to a smaller target in order to preserve MBR, bootloader, partition UUID(s) etc. OP, is that your goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your input device (`if=`) is 1TB in size, then our output file (`of=`) will also be 1TB.

`dd` is a very low-level tool that simply copies ALL bytes from the input stream to the output stream, regardless of what the data is or whether it's even allocated.  That even includes empty (`0x00`) sectors and those with garbage in them.  It does not concern itself with the high-level data structures that represent "files", "directories", etc.

If your goal is to get an exact bye-for-byte clone of the 1TB disk, you will need to pipe the data through a compression algorithm such as `bzip2` in order to fit it on a smaller disk.

If your goal is to merely back up your data, then `dd` is not the proper tool for that.  You'll want to use `tar` or some other archive tool instead.

Answer (score 2):

dd copies the underlying disk directly, not the filesystem.  It does not know about allocated blocks or unused space.

If you want to capture just the filesystem, and it's a Linux EXTx filesystem that's not mounted, I'd suggest shrinking it down to minimum size (must be unmounted and fsck'd first) using

```
resize2fs -M /dev/sd??
```

Then copy the partition the filesystem is on onto your backup disk.

To restore the ripest stem back to its original size (get your free space back), run

```
resize2fs /dev/Ed??
```

Better yet, use a file system-aware archive tool like tar.

Comment: OP mentioned cloning the whole disk. Resized filesystem (if there is one partition only) should fit all the data into the target disk and it is OK. However the cloned partition table would be incorrect for the smaller disk and that may confuse some tools. To avoid future trouble the partition(s) should be shrunk as well.

Comment: True that the partition table would still be set for the larger size. I did say to copy the partition not the disk. What I omitted is how to grow the file system back to the partition size afterwards, which could be done on both the original and backup devices. I figured this would steer the OP in the right direction but isn't the right place for a full tutorial on disks and file systems...

Answer (score 0):

> This is a bit weird how 10% of 1Tb filled 300Gb space.

Nope. **100%** of 1TB filled 300GB space and wanted more.

Think of it as a notebook with 100 pages and notes on the first 10 pages.
If you put the notebook on a Xerox style copier and copy the whole book you will end up with 100 new pages. Even if most of them are blank.

Using dd is a RAW copy. It does not copy data in use. For that you would need something which understands the difference between filled pages and pages with just empty lines on it.

> Can anyone explain me this thing, why this happened? Did my data get corrupt?

No, you just gave a command to do something else than you wanted.